Unable to mount disk image after creating in Arch
I have quite the problem right now. I have created a disk image of my Arch install by using this command sudo dd if=/dev/sdX bs=8M | pv -cN source | zstd | pv -cN zstd > out.img.zst, then decompressing the image when needed (at the time I was transitioning to using ZFS as root): zstd -dk out.img.zst
but any tool I try to use to mount this image fails. mount, losetup, all of them fail to read any usable data from this image. Am I doing anything wrong? I've also tried listing the partitions with tools like fdisk and parted but they detect nothing. Is this backup done for?

I figured out my issue. The drive was partitioned with 4096 byte sectors, while the image had 512. I specified 4096 when using mount and it worked.
Edit: I used the following command: sudo mount -o offset=$((4096*262400)) out.img /mnt/arch
Apologies for not providing one before.

"I specified 4096 when using mount" – Not really. You specified the offset as 1074790400. My point is mount is not able to tell if you used $((4096*262400)) or $((512*2099200)) or e.g. $((51200*20992)); and the loop device your mount created most likely used 512-byte logical sectors anyway. If 262400 is the start sector of a partition and the sectors were 4096-byte then offset=$((4096*262400)) is right, offset=$((512*2099200)) is equally right; neither specifies 4096 as anything. offset=$((512*262400)) would be wrong, but it's not clear this is what you originally used.
